# Get inner value of a xml node inside a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've a xml file with 10 "item entries" in the following format:

```
<channel>
    <title>Search products</title>
    <link>http://v2-bienaldolivrosp.rxnova.com/feeds/search/Products/?startRecord=1</link>
    <description>Bienal do Livro de Sao Paulo search</description>
    <language>pt-BR</language>
    <item>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.bienaldolivrosp.com.br/pt-BR/Exhibitors/376354/Manole-Conteudo/Products/716223/Gestao-de-Pessoas-4-ed-O-Novo-Papel-dos-Recursos-Humanos-nas-Organizacoes</guid>
        <link>http://www.bienaldolivrosp.com.br/pt-BR/Exhibitors/376354/Manole-Conteudo/Products/716223/Gestao-de-Pessoas-4-ed-O-Novo-Papel-dos-Recursos-Humanos-nas-Organizacoes</link>
        <title>Gestão de Pessoas 4ª ed. - O Novo Papel dos Recursos Humanos nas Organizações</title>
        <description>A obra parte dos novos desafios da gestão de pessoas e direciona a atenção do leitor para seis ações que, inerentemente, se conectam em rede: agregar, recompensar, desenvolver, monitorar, manter e, por fim, aplicar pessoas. </description>
        <pubDate>Fri, 25 Jul 2014 20:17:53 Z</pubDate>
        <enclosure url="http://www.bienaldolivrosp.com.br/__novaimages/596889" type="image/jpg" length="1000" />
    </item>
</channel>
```

I'm running the following code to parse the xml:

```
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
   text += values[i]['title'] + " - " + "<br>";
}
```

The above code works fine but the problem is that I need to get the url inside de "enclosure url" node and I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
text +=
    values[i]['title'] + " - " +
    values[i]['enclosure'].getAttribute('url') +
    " - " +
    "<br>"
;
```

I may be wrong but... ^_^
I expect it will give output like:

```
"Gestão de Pessoas 4ª ed. - O Novo Papel dos Recursos Humanos nas Organizações - http://www.bienaldolivrosp.com.br/__novaimages/596889 - <br>"
```

### Version 0.2:

```
text += values[i]['title'] + " - ";
if ( typeof values[i]['enclosure'] === 'undefined' ) {
    text += 'Undefined Enclosure';
} else {
    console.log( values[i]['enclosure'] );
    text += values[i]['enclosure'].getAttribute('url');
}
```

Comment: Almost... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

Comment: I think ...of undefined... means no ['enclosure'] found. Could it be that there is some xml element without that field? Could you check all of those?

Comment: Thank you. That's interesting. If each of your values is typical XML DOM object then it's wierd that they have ['title'] property at all. Those look like well formed simple object. Wait - are we talking about client-side Javascript or server-side one? What commands/libraries are you using to process XML? How does that array of value produced? // if any value is XML DOM then you could use values[i].getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')... but now I doubt that it'll work. I need to see more javascript-code to be sertain ^_^

Comment: Hey! There is one item without 'enclosure' field. Look at 7-th title=Coleção nomes e palavras

Comment: Added version 0.2. Try it with opened javascript console. If you are using browser-side javascript then even if you get error - you will see the structure of your values[i]['enclosure'] and by seing it's members you can find a way to get that url from it. Javascript console is avaliable in Firefox or Google Chrome - in Webdeveloper tool out of box. Firefox Ctrl+shift+K, Chrome - I don't remember but maybe Ctrl+Shift+J (windows, perhaps other platforms too)

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort. Unfortunately it's still not working. I'm getting the following result: Undefined Enclosure, nothing on console. I'm getting the xml via GET ajax from a rss url.